# Подключение GUI к БД

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Работаю с библиотекой JavaFX, и вот не понимаю вообще,как мне к GUI подключить БД, или лучше сделать коллекции значений,чтобы они были в роли бд?

Comment: используйте jdbc

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример того, что у Вас не получается. Если кратко, то: GUI -> Модель -> БД.